# Define in Makefile

Tags: makefile

I've got such a structure of files and directories:

```
.
├── Makefile
└── packages
    ├── Makefile
    └── subdir
        └── Makefile
```

and top Makefile looks like this:

```
define aa
    make -C $1 $2
endef

packages=$(shell find ./packages -type d)
p1=$(filter-out . .., $(packages))

all:
    $(foreach f,$(p1),$(call aa,$(f),compile))
```

and both of Makefiles in ./packages/ and ./packages/subdir/ have "compile" target.

I'm trying to invoke all of Makefiles automatically in "packages" subdirectory without adding them individually into Makefile.

When I run make in top directory I got error:

```
make -C ./packages compile  make -C ./packages/subdir compile
make[1]: *** packages/subdir: No such file or directory.  Stop.
Makefile:16: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I'm wondering why both invocations of make  (which should be separate invocations) are placed in one line?

When I add end-of-line at the end of the "aa" macro like this:

```
define aa
    make -C $1 $2

endef
```

everything works as expected.
My question is why this macro doesn't work without this end-of-line?

Answer (score 1):

Because a the variable definition starts after the newline which follows the `define`, and ends before the newline preceding the endef.

Quoting the gnumake manual :

> The value in an ordinary assignment cannot contain a newline; but the newlines that separate the lines of the value in a define become part of the variable’s value (except for the final newline which precedes the endef and is not considered part of the value).

So your define is equivalent to `aa = make -C $1 $2` and since foreach does not add anything between each expansion, you got that result.